# Social Engine, Articles editing

Tags: socialengine

I'll put this in the best way I can.

As an admin, I can currently edit the articles of a user by one of the 2 ways:

Edit the article via the View articles page OR

Go to the view articles page, select the name, go to View Users and then login into that particular users profile and edit the article.

I prefer the first method but, its a bit tooo tedious when Im editing multiple articles from the same person.

I was wondering if there was a way in which, i could just get all the articles of the user inside the admin panel and edit them there itself.

Any help in this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as bulk editing (several articles by some condition) in Social Engine. But you can ask developers for usability improve, new team (since January) doing great with updates :)